# I have a question in Basic HTML

Tags: html-editor

What does it mean to edit a website directly? My professor tells us not to use an editor. I'm not sure how to do so either.

Comment: This question is off-topic and the instruction to not use an editor makes no sense. No matter what you do, you have to use an editor. Your professor probably said "Don't use a WYSIWYG editor". To that I would add "pay attention to details" and "[read the docs](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/)".

Comment: Take a look at Sublime, PHPStorm, Eclipse/Aptana or Netbeans. Close vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This basically means you do not want to use, say "Microsoft Word" to edit your code.  Doing so may (and often will) add unnecessary bits of information to the code... causing it to parse unexpectedly when viewed in a browser.

Instead, you a code editor (like Adobe Dreamweaver, or a free alternative like Notepad++) to edit any code.  These types of programs are designed specifically for code editing.